# Частичный update

Tags: spring-mvc, jpa, update, freemarker

так как являюсь начинающим программистом, то у меня возникла проблема с редактированием записи в БД
Есть контроллер `(/main)` для добавления данных из формы и `(/update)` для редактирования

```
@PostMapping("/main")
    public String add(
            @AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
            @RequestParam String message, Status status, Map<String, Object> model) {
        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(new Date(), message, user,  status);
        ticketRepos.save(ticket);
        Iterable<Ticket> tickets = ticketRepos.findAll();
        model.put("tickets", tickets);
        return "redirect:/main";
    }

метод add работает отлично, но с методом modify  напутал

@PostMapping("/update")
public String modify (
        @RequestParam Status status, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket (status);
    statusModifyRepos.save(ticket);
    Iterable<Ticket> tickets  = statusModifyRepos.statusModify(ticket.getId(),ticket.getStatus().name());
   model.put("messages", tickets);
    return "redirect:/main";
}

Есть интерфейс в котором я делаю update  для поля status
 @Modifying
    @Query("update Ticket t set t.status = :status where t.id = :id")
    List<Ticket>  statusModify(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("status") String status);

И сама форма freemarker в которой ввожу данные из выпадающего списка
<strike>
<form method="post">
   <select name="ticket" class="form-control-sm" >
     <option value="${ticket.status.setNameStatus("Выполнение")}" label="Выполнение"/>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="${_csrf.token}" />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Записать</button>
 </form>
  </div>
</strike>
```

При выполнение получаю ошибку( Где- то напутал, самому разобраться не хватает знаний. Спасибо за любую помощь!